# Is quickbitcoins.net reputable?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

Mailed in cash with postal envelope. Website started acknowledging receipt via postal delivery 3 weeks since. Blockchain within 3 hours of "caught up". Yet no bitcoins.

Is it a scam?

Cash amount was small, should not pose problem. Was what you call "pilot test" and had bitcoins arrived promptly would be followed with larger purchase.

Comment: I don't know of a problem with them. Did you check at http://blockchain.info/ if your address has received coins? What do quickbitcoins have to say on the matter?

Comment: They provide a phone # on a post on this thread: http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=92026.msg1239487#msg1239487

Comment: Burner cellphone too expensive to inquire 50 euros.

Comment: Ok, well then you could post a reply in that thread or PM to the forum user.

Comment: While QuickBitcoins may offer to accept cash via mail, sending cash in the mail is generally considered an inadvisable activity due to the high likelihood that your mail will be "lost" by a dishonest person handling the mail somewhere along the delivery path.

Comment: Anonymousness more important than occasional stolen envelopes. Website confirms payment received, but no bitcoins have arrived.

Answer (score 4):

I used quickbitcoins.net successfully 4 times. They are gone now. The 800 number is disconnected and their e-mail address returns nothing. Try to find the http: website on Explorer or on tor and neither can find it! Site no longer exists! If you send coins to them without checking you will loose your money!

Answer (score 3):

See http://bitcoin-otc.com/viewratingdetail.php?nick=QuickBitcoins

The owner of QuickBitcoins and his wife have been on #bitcoin-otc for quite some time. I've had successful trades with them before they ran QuickBitcoins, but never through the site itself.

For any problem you might be having with the site, I'd definitely recommend contacting them. In my anecdotal experience, Aethero (the site's operator) and lucidlepidoptera (his wife) have had great communication. Try info@quickbitcoins.net, or jump on IRC and go to [#bitcoin-otc on freenode.net](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=#bitcoin-otc). They're usually there with the nickname "QuickBitcoins".

Answer (score 2):

We're very sorry about this experience. At the moment it doesn't look like we have any open cash in mail orders so either we have 1) Filled this order or 2) Not received the cash. Please feel free to email us at info@quickbitcoins.net or call us any time at 1-888-959-3166 to work out where the problem is. Please make sure to reference your order number.

Comment: Email has been transmitted. Please be checking spam folder.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who asks you for money but hides his identity, is automatically non-reputable, almost by definition...

```
looris@Palace-of-the-Nine-Moons:~ $ whois quickbitcoins.net

Whois Server Version 2.0

Domain names in the .com and .net domains can now be registered
with many different competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net
for detailed information.

   Domain Name: QUICKBITCOINS.NET
   Registrar: ENOM, INC.
   Whois Server: whois.enom.com
   Referral URL: http://www.enom.com
   Name Server: DNS1.REGISTRAR-SERVERS.COM
   Name Server: DNS2.REGISTRAR-SERVERS.COM
   Name Server: DNS3.REGISTRAR-SERVERS.COM
   Name Server: DNS4.REGISTRAR-SERVERS.COM
   Name Server: DNS5.REGISTRAR-SERVERS.COM
   Status: clientTransferProhibited
   Updated Date: 02-jul-2012
   Creation Date: 29-apr-2012
   Expiration Date: 29-apr-2013

>>> Last update of whois database: Thu, 24 Jan 2013 08:56:40 UTC <<<

[...]

=-=-=-=

Registration Service Provided By: Namecheap.com
Contact: support@namecheap.com
Visit: http://namecheap.com

Domain name: quickbitcoins.net

Registrant Contact:
   WhoisGuard
   WhoisGuard Protected ()

   Fax:
   11400 W. Olympic Blvd. Suite 200
   Los Angeles, CA 90064
   US

Administrative Contact:
   WhoisGuard
   WhoisGuard Protected (f1523859958c4c18a48b1813ac61496e.protect@whoisguard.com)
   +1.6613102107
   Fax: +1.6613102107
   11400 W. Olympic Blvd. Suite 200
   Los Angeles, CA 90064
   US

Technical Contact:
   WhoisGuard
   WhoisGuard Protected (f1523859958c4c18a48b1813ac61496e.protect@whoisguard.com)
   +1.6613102107
   Fax: +1.6613102107
   11400 W. Olympic Blvd. Suite 200
   Los Angeles, CA 90064
   US

Status: Locked

Name Servers:
   dns1.registrar-servers.com
   dns2.registrar-servers.com
   dns3.registrar-servers.com
   dns4.registrar-servers.com
   dns5.registrar-servers.com

Creation date: 30 Apr 2012 02:30:00
Expiration date: 29 Apr 2013 18:30:00

[...]
```